# ClassNotFoundException with Java's -cp on Mac OS X

Tags: java, compiler-errors, classpath

I am trying to wrangle my professor's code which is organized in the following fashion:

```
home directory
  src
    bn
      base
      core
      parser
    util
```

I've managed to compile it all, but trying commands such as `java -cp src/bn/base Main` aren't working. I have tried variations of this as well but each time I get the following error message:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class Main
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: bn/base/Main (wrong name: Main)
```

(yes i have checked there is Main.java and Main.class in this directory)

Comment: `src` should not be part of the classpath.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.